# validate a textbox on textchanged but not on keypress

Tags: .net, winforms, validating

I am using Textbox_Validating event to validate a textbox on one of my window form.
I wanted to validate the textbox, if the text of the texbox changes. So I called the validating event from the textbox_Texchanged event. But it has a sideffect as soon as I press a key it fires the textchanged event and hence the text_Validating event. **I want to block the call to Text_Validating if the text property has changed due to keypress.** But if someone assings `txtbox.Text="asdf";`, I want to fire validating event in this case.

```
private void txt8Ydere1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt8Ydere1_Validating(sender,null);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the LostFocus event on the textbox to call the validation method?

Comment: @ImGreg ,I guess it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the LostFocus event for the textbox.  You could run your validation from that event.

See the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can block the call to validating event by doing this

```
txt8Ydere1.Validating-=txt8Ydere1_Validating;
```

place this code in **keydown,keyUp** events...

Check for `txtbox.Text equals "asdf"` and if so you can **directly call the Validating method without resubscribing to the event**:

```
txt8Ydere1_Validating(sender,null);
```

Comment: But if I call txt8Ydere1_Validating(sender,null); in TextChanged event, keydown event will result in text changed and simultaneously it will call txt8Ydere1_Validating(sender,null)